# How did the word 'being' evolve into different parts of speech (noun, adjective, conjuction, participle)?

Tags: etymology, parts-of-speech, polysemes

I'm trying to understand the different meanings of the word **being**.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/being):

> **being** (*noun*)
>
> 1 a: the quality or state of having existence 
> b (1): something that is conceivable and hence capable of existing
> (2): something that actually exists.
> (3): the totality of existing
> things. 
> c:  conscious existence.
>
> 2  the qualities that constitute an existent thing.
>
> 3 a living thing 
> *especially*: person
>
> ---
>
> **being** (*adjective*)
>
> : PRESENT — used in the phrase for the time being
>
> ---
>
> **being** (*conjuction*)
>
> chiefly dialectal 
> : SINCE, BECAUSE — usually used with as, as how, or that
>
> ---
>
> **being** (*participle*)
>
> present participle of BE.

Firstly, what is the relevant etymology of the word in each instant? Did they all derive from the same word, and if so, how did the four different parts of speech evolve?

[Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/being#etymonline_v_8263) gives the etymology of noun *being* as:

> c. 1300, "existence," in its most comprehensive sense, "condition, state, circumstances; presence, fact of existing," early 14c., existence," from be + -ing. The sense of "that which physically exists, a person or thing" (as in human being) is from late 14c.

This would seem to mean they all have the same source, yet somehow be distinct.
This is causing me some difficulty in understanding the fine differences between the several definitions.

I would appreciate some clear explanation of each one and the different rules which would apply etc. (rather than just a dictionary definition).

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What are your reasons to think that there are multiple sources?  Practice on this site is to show what research you‘ve done and in what ways it has failed to resolve your question.

Comment: Please narrow this down into a single, more focused question.

Comment: Your first 3 senses are all nouns, why do you have them labeled with different parts of speech?

Comment: The adjective and conjunction senses are separate from those definitions you quoted.

Comment: Anyway, all these meanings are ultimately derived from the verb "to be".

Comment: @paultanenbaum Maybe I've gone mad, but my brain is struggling to 'itemise' them as it were, and consider each usage independently. My question is less about etymology then about multiple, finely differentiated definitions of the same word. Also I struggled immensely with formatting the dictionary definition correctly, so it might require further editing by a veteran user...

Comment: As you note, those multiple definitions are “finely differentiated.” What is it about the differences that leads you to suspect that what you yourself call “the same word” might have more than one etymology?

Comment: Words can develop new senses by semantic extension which can include metaphorical extension. All related senses share the same etymological root as the original sense/usage  has that etymology. There are also homonyms which are unrelated in origin, like _bat_ (a stick used in games) or _bat_ (an animal); and there are polysemes  (polysemous homonyms) which share an origin.

Comment: @Barmar It was challenging to fix it on the phone but I've finally done it for the OP.

Comment: @ermanen Wow, I had enough trouble fixing the original formatting on a Mac....

Comment: Did your search engine not tell you this etymology, along with various terms in Greek, Latin and other tongues has Indo-European roots reaching back prolly 9,000 years and possibly much farther?

I believe 'be' with 'do' and 'have' are by far - no pun intended - the most important verbs in English; prolly in all Germanic tongues.

Doesn't having that great value for that great time make the ubiquity of any 'be' form more obviously likely than remarkable?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin That very vaguely explains the general etymology. It does not however explain the 'evolutionary branches' of the several different modern usages of the word. Also, see clarified question as edited above.

Comment: Sorry Ben. That was a Comment, not your Answer. How much detail would you like on a topic loosely spread across most of history and half of Europe, at least? Compare your pseudonym's 'sohn' to 'sen' or 'son'?

Compare the English '…borough/burro/burrow/bury…' to all the '…berg/burgh'… and similar place names across Europe, named for the action of building their walls, and isn't the etymology of digging a grave to 'bury' someone obvious?